# Angular2 http request depends on data returned from other response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have created a service, which have different http calls with diff params.
**quote.service.ts**

```
getQuotes(){
    let params = {
        "Type": "BasicDetail",
    }
    return this.http.post(this.url,params)
    .map(res => res.json())
}  

getOptions(){
    let params = {
        "Type": "Hoteloption",
    }
    return this.http.post(this.url,params)
    .map(res=>res.json())
}

getServiceWiseOptions(){
    let params = {
        "Type": "ServiceWiseOption",
    }
    return this.http.post(this.url,params)
    .map(res=>res.json())
}
```

I call below `getOption()`in my component code in `constructor`

**component.ts**

```
getOption() {
 this.quoteService.getQuotes().mergeMap( quotes => {
  if(this.quotes.BasicDetails[0].QuotType == 'QUOTTYP-3'){
    return this.quoteService.getServiceWiseOptions()
  }
  else{
    return this.quoteService.getOptions()
  }
})
 .subscribe(
  options => {
    this.optionsdata = options.resultData;             
    if(this.quotes.BasicDetails[0].QuotType == 'QUOTTYP-3'){
      this.servicewiseData = options.resultData.ServiceWiseOption;
    }else{                
      this.servicewiseData = options.resultData.Hoteloption; 
    }    
  },
  )
}
```

What I need is to call `getServiceWiseOptions()` and `getOptions()` from service based on response of `getOption()` if I get `QuotType:` `getServiceWiseOptions()` otherwise `getOptions()`.

Above function `getOption()` works sometime but it doesn't call either of these function sometimes.

Please give me some suggestions what should I do?
I think its problem with `mergeMap()`

Comment: can you send the response of `getQuotes()` method, is there any big reason using `mergeMap` instaead of `map`?

Comment: @Sravan No specific reason to use `mergeMap()`. I don't know about that someone told me to do that but that is not working well

Comment: @Sravan As per current code if I don't use `mergeMap` getting error `Property 'resultData' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'`

Comment: what is the result of `quotes` you get in your `getOption()` response

Comment: @Sravan Ok let me show  you  json Response from the `getOption`

Comment: is there any specific case when it is not working? you may not be getting the same data everyrime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153683/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-sravan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getOption()` function, you reffered your response with `this`, which makes it a controller variable instead of `response` data,

So change `this.quotes` to `quotes`

```
getOption() {
 this.quoteService.getQuotes().mergeMap( quotes => {
    this.quotes = quotes; // this line if you want it to use anywhere else
  if(quotes.BasicDetails[0].QuotType == 'QUOTTYP-3'){
    return this.quoteService.getServiceWiseOptions()
  }
  else{
    return this.quoteService.getOptions()
  }
})
 .subscribe(
  options => {
    this.optionsdata = options.resultData;             
    if(this.quotes.BasicDetails[0].QuotType == 'QUOTTYP-3'){
      this.servicewiseData = options.resultData.ServiceWiseOption;
    }else{                
      this.servicewiseData = options.resultData.Hoteloption; 
    }    
  },
  )
}
```